# Date comparison between same data type in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a column in the format -

```
MAX_DATE                                PROCESS_DATE
2022-10-14T16:09:09.272+00:00           2022-11-08T15:43:29.027+00:00
```

WHEN I AM WRITING THE CONDITION

```
SELECT * FROM ANC 
WHERE MAX_DATE > PROCESS_DATE
```

Even then a lot of rows are coming although they do not fulfill the condition. The date format of both is the same, i am not sure how to change both of them in the same date format, i tried the below but still I am getting all rows so the above condition is not working

```
SELECT * FROM ANC 
WHERE TO_DATE(to_char(MAX_DATE,'DD-MM-YYY'),'DD-MM-YYY') > TO_DATE(to_char(PROCESS_DATE,'DD-MM-YYY'),'DD-MM-YYY')
```

Also this is giving me the output like

```
MAX_DATE                                PROCESS_DATE
2022-10-14T00:00:00.000+00:00           2022-11-08T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

How to compare both the dates ?

Comment: What is the data type of each column?  `SELECT TABLE_NAME 
, COLUMN_NAME 
, DATA_TYPE 
, DATA_LENGTH 
, DATA_PRECISION 
, DATA_SCALE 
, NULLABLE 
FROM ALL_tab_columns 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('MAX_DATE', 'PROCESS_DATE')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns have a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type then just compare the columns directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ANC 
WHERE  MAX_DATE > PROCESS_DATE
```

If your columns have the `VARCHAR2` data type then, firstly, that is bad practice and you should alter the table and change the data type to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and secondly, if you are going to keep them as strings then you need to convert them to timestamps using the `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function before comparing them:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ANC 
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(MAX_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
         > TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(PROCESS_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with below query

```
where 
convert(datetime, MAX_DATE)  >= convert(datetime,PROCESS_DATE)
```

Comment: In Oracle, the [`CONVERT` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions027.htm) changes strings from one character set to another character set; how does that help the OP solve their problem?